# ads not showing with proguard

Tags: android, admob, proguard

i am new in admob and also proguard . i have made an app which is about to release in two days . i have used proguard and admob . test ads were showing but at that time i had not used proguard . after debugging and all the stuff i generated signed apk with proguard . but it is not showing ads . it has passed a weak .

i know that new admob account takes time to show ads but i have other app which i made before a month . when i had placed google ads in that app , ads were showing only after one day . and that app is also showing add today . both app has 1 - 5 user . but new app is not showing any ad .

i have included keep in proguardrules.pro

```
-keep public class com.google.android.gms.ads.**{
   public** ;
}
-keep public class com.google.ads.**{
   public** ;
}
```

i do not know whether it is problem due to proguard or admob is not showing ads . i have more 300 request ( 15 users ) but match rate is 0 .

Thank You .

Comment: Do test ads show up with test keys in debug build (without proguard) ?

Comment: @abhijeet soni test ads are working fine . i disable proguard by setting             minifyEnabled false . i think i disable proguard . test are also showing with minifyEnabled true .